# Wrong icons shown in reputation drop down

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

While on the academia SE, I clicked on the reputation button and saw this:

[image]

I actually don't recognise the icon next to all those StackOverflow reputation changes, but it's obviously not correct. On SO it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For me, the icon is different even when I'm on SO. It also appears incorrectly for some (but not all) of the **Featured on Meta** items.

Comment: That's the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) icon. It may be related to either [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379710/1099857) or the related fix.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happens every time a new site is launched (see [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303883/323179)); one site just started private beta today. If you wait it resolves itself.

Comment: Thanks @Laurel, certainly looks like that.